# Linked list — deletion of nodes which contain prime numbers

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have written a code in the C language  which will create a linked list. The linked list structre has two fields, namely `data` and `next`; `data` contains integer data, `next` is a structure pointer.

The program asks the user to input data into the list. Once the data has been entered, the program will go through the list and check which data in the node contains a prime number. If it finds one such node, it will delete it and link the next node to the previous node, but I am getting a segmentation fault error and I am unable to solve.

I am putting below the code. *Can you please be kind enough to help me solve it as I do not know how to find the problem?*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *nptr;
nptr H, h, n;

void deletetheprime(struct node**);
void display();
int prime(int);

int main() {
    nptr temp1, temp;
    int i, N, p;
    printf("\n if list is completed enter 999\n");
    for (;;) {
        printf("\n enter the data \n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if (i == 999)
            break;
        else
        if (H == NULL) {
            H = h = (nptr)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            H->data = i;
            H->next = NULL;
        } else {
            n = (nptr)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            n->data = i;
            n->next = NULL;
            h->next = n;
            h = n;
        }
    }
    printf("\n data before deletion\n");
    display();
    temp = H;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        N = temp->next->data;
        p = prime(N);
        if (p == 1) {
            deletetheprime(&temp);
        } else {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n the data after deletion is\n");
    display();
    return 0;
}

void deletetheprime(struct node **temp2) {
    nptr temp, temp1;
    temp = *temp2;
    temp1 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp->next->next;

    free(temp1);
    temp = temp->next;
}

int prime(int i) {
    int j, p = 0;
    for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; i++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j > i / 2) {
        p = 1;
    }
    return p;
}

void display() {
    nptr temp;
    temp = H;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("\n %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: "*please solve it*": SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is *really* going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs here, in main

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    N=temp->next->data;
...
```

You are checking if `temp` is not `NULL`, which is correct, but accessing data of `next` node, which **can** be `NULL`, and **has** to be `NULL` near the end of the list, which leads to undefined behavior.

Simply modify it to

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    N=temp->data;
...
```

Where you are sure that temp isn't `NULL` and you won't get segmentation error here. And it'll work.

Or if you need to access data of `temp->next->next` node, you've got to check if `next->next` isn't `NULL` as well.

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    if (temp->next->next != NULL)
    {
        N=temp->next->data;
    }
    else // temp->next->next is NULL so you can't access the data
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while (temp != NULL) {
    N = temp->next->data;
```

When you reach the last element of the list, `temp` is not `NULL`, but `temp->next` is so `temp->next->data` has undefined behavior.

There are other problems:

- your `prime()` function is inefficient and will return `1` for `0` and `1`.
- you `deletetheprime()` function deletes the node and updates the pointer in the callers scope, but the caller does not update the link in the previous node nor the `H` pointer if the deleted node is the first.
- you use global variables for no good reason, you should pass `H` to `display()` and make all variables local in `main()`.
- you never free the allocated objects, it is good style to free everything you allocate.
- you should not hide pointers behind typedefs, make `node` a typedef for `struct node` but keep pointers visible, it is a good habit to avoid confusing both the reader and the programmer.

To delete the node, you should use the pointer to link trick:

```
for (struct node **p = &H; *p;) {
    if (prime((*p)->data) {
        nptr np = *p;
        *p = np->next;
        free(np);
    } else {
        p = &(*p)->next;
    }
}
```

`p` initially points to the head pointer `H` and subsequently points to the `next` member of the previous node. It can be used to update the head pointer or the link in the previous node when a node to be deleted is found.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int isprime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void display(const node *temp) {
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    node *H = NULL;
    node **lastp = &H;
    node *n;
    int i;
    printf("Enter values, when list is completed enter 999\n");
    for (;;) {
        printf("\n enter the data: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1 || i == 999)
            break;

        n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
        if (n == NULL)
            break;
        n->data = i;
        n->next = NULL;
        *lastp = n;
        lastp = &n->next;
    }
    printf("\n data before deletion: ");
    display(H);

    for (node **p = &H; *p;) {
        if (isprime((*p)->data)) {
            n = *p;
            *p = n->next;
            free(n);
        } else {
            p = &(*p)->next;
        }
    }

    printf("\n the data after deletion is: ");
    display(H);

    /* free the list */
    while (H != NULL) {
        n = H;
        H = n->next;
        free(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

I shall attribute your *please solve it!* stance to your poor command of the English language. Please learn to improve both your communications and your programming skills by carefully studying answers on this site.